# Getting error while publishing video file stream in chrome latest version 87

Tags: angular, google-chrome, opentok

We are getting error while publishing vedio file stream in chrome 87 latest version. It is working fine while downgraded the chrome version.
We are using captureStream() method to get the media stream. We are getting MediaStream active false on latest version, but same code is working fine on downgraded version.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhAng.png)

We have referred below opentok code:
https://github.com/opentok/opentok-web-samples/tree/master/Publish-Video